# What distribution pluffy to buy for an aspiring econometrician?

Tags: distributions

My girlfriend is an Actuarial Analyst at a large insurance company in the Netherlands and because we'll soon have our two year anniversary, I thought of gifts for her.

On [Proof: Math is beautiful](http://proofmathisbeautiful.tumblr.com/post/5104877044/baseln-statistical-distribution-plushies-am) I discovered these [Distribution pluffies](http://www.etsy.com/listing/71739287/collection-of-10-distribution-plushies).

So here's my question: What distribution is of the most relevance in the field of an econometrician?

The available pluffies are:

- Standard Normal Distribution
- t Distribution
- Chi-Square Distribution
- Log Normal Distribution
- Continuous Uniform Distribution
- Weibull Distribution
- Cauchy Distribution
- Poisson Distribution
- Gumbel Distribution
- Erlang Distribution

Any help much appreciated.

**EDIT:** Thanks a lot for all the suggestions despite this being just off-topic! I'll get her the t Distribution pluffy.

Comment: Buy her a vacuum; chicks love gifts like that.

Comment: Sounds silly, but how about choosing on the basis of colour? (Otherwise, I would probably second the Cauchy choice -- although a positive distribution with infinite mean might be better if you want to indicate something about the depth of your affection ...)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You gotta get her one with some Kurtosis. Maybe the t-distribution. And be sure and write a loving note along the lines of, "Baby, when I think of fat tails, I think of you. Your kurtosis makes you non-normal."

My wife digs it when I get sappy like that. I have the scars to prove it.

Comment: So, when is the divorce final?

Comment: No such thing as too many tail puns.

Comment: Liked the suggestion about the note. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6):

You're in big trouble if you're asking us for gift advice.

Comment: True, we don't have a vested interest and we may want to be funny (which may appear we are mean). Unless you want to cut us in a deal.

Answer (score 2):

Insurance is all about skewed distributions with long tails: think amount of loss. These also typically have only positive values. The log-normal distribution looks most like one of those. Another good option is the Gumbel distribution, which comes up in extreme value theory.

Answer (score 2):

Aren't [econometricians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What%27s_that_got_to_do_with_the...?) concerned with the [price of t (distributions) in China](http://supertart.com/priceofteainchina/index.php)?  It has the large (on occasion, infinite) kurtosis recommended by @JD Long, too.

Answer (score 0):

From the list I would pick standard normal. After all regression is the main tool of econometrician and usually econometrician can rely only on asymptotic results, hence standard normal rules them all :)

Having said that I would not like to get a standard normal distribution pluffy (I am not a girl, but can be considered econometrician) for standard normal is so widely used that it is a bit mundane. So you can choose log-normal, since econometricians use log-log regression extensively or Cauchy as a reminder, that not all distributions have finite moments.

Comment: His GF could misunderstand Cauchy: "or Cauchy as a reminder, that *not all distributions have finite moments*.". :P

Comment: @Roman, good catch :)